# Stop runaway recursion to make Python function work properly

Tags: python, recursion, stack-overflow

I'm trying to write a function that returns the total sum of the products of the elements in the same positions in two lists using recursion.
I tried various code to stop the recursion error (exceeding maximum recursion depth.) Can you help me to make this function properly?

P.S. Must use recursion!!

```
def dot(l1, l2):
if len(l1)==len(l2):

    newl1=l1[1:]

    newl2=l2[1:]

    else_dot = dot (newl1, newl2)

    if len(newl1) == 1:
         return l1[-1]*l2[-1]
return l1[0] * l2[0] + else_dot

dot([5, 3], [6, 4])
```

Comment: Fix your indentation. It's absolutely critical that it's 100% correct when writing Python.

Answer (score 0):

One simple rework of your code to get it basically running would be:

```
def dot(l1, l2):
    if len(l1) > 0 and len(l2) > 0:

        newl1 = l1[1:]
        newl2 = l2[1:]

        else_dot = dot(newl1, newl2)

        return l1[0] * l2[0] + else_dot

    return 0

print(dot([5, 3], [6, 4]))
```

Though we could probably do better.  When I first read your question, I thought you were up against `RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded` because your potential data was greater than ~1,000 pairs -- only later I realized you got the error with just two elements as your base case was out of whack.  So, I actually worked on the more data than the size of the stack issue first:

Below's an approach to push the list length limit from a thousand elements to a quarter million elements.  We don't get around the stack limitation but rather split our use of the stack in half, so that we're recursively processing at most 500 lists of 500 elements instead of one list of 1,000 elements:

```
from random import randint
from sys import getrecursionlimit

LIMIT = getrecursionlimit() // 2  # use half the stack for each branch of recursion

def dot(l1, l2):
    len1, len2 = len(l1), len(l2)

    if len1 > 0 < len2:

        if len1 <= LIMIT >= len2:
            head1, *tail1 = l1
            head2, *tail2 = l2

            return head1 * head2 + dot(tail1, tail2)
        else:
            return dot(l1[:LIMIT], l2[:LIMIT]) + dot(l1[LIMIT:], l2[LIMIT:])

    return 0

a = [randint(1, 100) for _ in range(LIMIT * 200)]
b = [randint(1, 100) for _ in range(LIMIT * 200)]

# Two lists contain 100,000 random numbers from 1 to 100 for a result of ~250,000,000
# Python recursion limit is ~1,000 calls, so instead of hitting the limit at ~1,000
# list elements, we hit it just under 250,000 ((1000 // 2) ** 2) list elements.

print(dot(a, b))
```

Adjusting `sys.setrecursionlimit()`, we can increase our limit by a factor of 100 or 1000 or more.